# How to get the Value on GridDataBound from Controller by passing Id from View in ASP.Net MVC Application?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, grid

I am working on an ASP.NET MVC 4 project at our company. In some code, first I load the grid from Controller. After that I want to change the row color based on `id`.  How do I get the value on `GridDataBound` from Controller by passing `id` from View in the ASP.Net MVC Application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not complicated and client-server process! Just set view engine (like **Razor**) for related page to show each row (may be decussate) to meat your purpose. Like using an `int` counter to find *odd* and *even* lines by `%` operation remainder, then set the appropriate style.